# Extract tweets that match a string of words exactly

Tags: python, regex, string, twitter

I am trying to get tweets that have an exact match to a string.

Here is the code:

```
query = "last dance"
language="en"
results = api.search(q=query, lang=language, count=200)
```

But I get results involving tweets that have the words last and dance separately. But I want tweets that have the words **last dance** together.

Comment: This looks like more of a question as to what exactly your `api.search()` method expects as the query argument. Based on the output it's returning, it's splitting by a space and matching results that have either "last" or "dance".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, make sure to URL encode these queries before making the request. There are several online tools to help you to do that, or you can search at twitter.com/search and copy the encoded URL from the browser’s address bar. The table below shows some example mappings from search queries to URL encoded queries:

```
Search query    URL encoded query
#haiku #poetry  %23haiku+%23poetry
“happy hour” :) %22happy%20hour%22%20%3A%29
```

Note that the space character can be represented by “%20” or “+” sign.

For more info - https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/standard-operators